# Convert javascript code to puppeteer with .pop method

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, variadic-functions

I'm new to puppeteer and I try to convert this javascript code :

```
let messageElement;
await driver.findElements(By.className("message-list-item")).then(
    (ok) => {
        messageElement = ok.pop()
    }
)

await messageElement.getAttribute("id").then(
    (ok) => {
        messageNum = parseInt(ok.split("message")[1]);
    }
)
```

The ".pop()" method need to be convert and I know with puppeteer we can use "length - 1" but I can't.
I've tried this :

```
const el = await page.$('.message-list-item')
  .then( (elements) => elements[el.length - 1]);
```

But not work.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with "converting .pop() to puppeteer". `pop` is a standard function on the Array prototype. According to the puppeteer [docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.3&show=api-pageselector), the `page.$(<selector>)` performs a `querySelector` on the DOM nodes, which returns the DOM node **directly** rather than an array of DOM nodes, so you don't need to use `pop` or any other Array function.

```
const el = await page.$('.message-list-item')
  .then( (element) => element));
```

which is equivalent to

```
const el = await page.$('.message-list-item');
```

**EDIT**

If you want the last element with that classname, then you need to get a list of those items, for which you can use `$$` which according to the docs uses `querySelectorAll`, and then get the last element.

```
const el = await page.$$('.message-list-item', (e) => e[e.length - 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks but I've try to got the last webelement, how can I do with pupetter ?

Answer (score 0):

With :

```
const h4All = await page.$$('.message-list-item');
  const h4Count = h4All.length;
  const fileName = h4All[h4Count - 1];

  const id= await (await fileName.getProperty("id")).jsonValue();
  console.log(await id);
  messageNum = parseInt(id.split("message")[1]);

  console.log(messageNum);
```

It's work, thanks for your help !
Can I ask you another problem ?
I've this javascript :

```
let messageNum = 0;
   let lastMessageElement
    let y = false;
                while(!y){
                    console.log("Message de recherche " + messageNum);
    
                    await driver.findElement(By.id("message"+messageNum.toString())).then(
                        
                        (ok) => {
                            console.log("Trouvé");
    
                            y = true;
                            lastMessageElement = ok;
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.log("Error");
                        }
                    )
                    
                    if(!y) await driver.sleep(5000);
                }
```

Try to convert in puppeteer:

```
let messageNum = 0;
   let lastMessageElement
    let y = false;
          while(!y){
              console.log("Message de recherche " + messageNum);
    
              const lastMessageElement = await page.$$("message"+messageNum.toString());
              console.log(lastMessageElement);
                 
    
              if (lastMessageElement) 
              {
                 
                  
                      console.log("Trouvé");
                      console.log(lastMessageElement);
                      y = true;
              }
                  else {
                      console.log("Error");
                  }
              
             
              if(!y) await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
          }
```

But it's not good ...
Thanks again